# Removing a character from a string once

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given this variable with a string type:

`var = "Apples"`

How can I delete the letter "p" only once? So that the result looks like this:

`var = "Aples"`

Comment: You need to say more about what your problem looks like in general. Do you only care about the letter "p", or any repeats? Will there always be exactly two "p"s? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) built in method for that:

```
a="Apples"
print(a.replace("p","",1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.replace()` built in method for that:

```
var="Apples"
print(var.replace('p','',1))
```

Comment: You realise this answer was already posted by Himaprasoon 8 minutes ago?